# Unclear if future times out or fails immediately

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have the following Actor:

```
class SomeActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case StartMessage =>
  //check if the job is still running
  val address = url("http://mywebsite.com")
  val status: Future[String] = Await.ready(Http(address OK as.String), 1 second)
  val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
  println("TIME NOW: " + now)

  status onComplete {
    case Success(message) => sender ! SomeMessage(message)
    case Failure(_) => {
      val then = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
      sender ! SomeMessage("Not running")
      println("TIME THEN: " + then)
    }
   }
```

And I am testing it like this:

```
  it should "check the id of a submitted job" in new Scope {
    myActorRef ! StartMessage
    expectMsg(SomeMessage("Not running"))   
  }
```

The problem is that I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for SomeMessage(Not running)
```

So it seems that my the future times out, which shouldn't be the case since I'm waiting for it only 1 second.

However, this is also printed.

```
TIME NOW: Tue Dec 06 13:39:13 GMT 2016
TIME THEN: Tue Dec 06 13:39:13 GMT 2016
```

From this, it seems that the future fails immediately after starting.

So which is it?

Comment: Don't await within an `Actor`. Better is to avoid nesting async `Future` producing code in an `Actor`. Bad things always happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the "closing over sender" problem, which is very well explained here:

http://helenaedelson.com/?p=879

Basically, I was replying to the `sender` in another thread, so the `sender` object may not be the same as the one from the main thread.

I just needed to add at the beginning:

```
val requestor = sender
```

and also change to:

```
requestor ! SomeMessage(message)
```

and

```
requestor ! SomeMessage("Not running")
```